# Who can see the name of the users who voted to close a question, before the actual closure takes place?

Tags: discussion

I know that when a question is put on hold or closed, the list of those who voted to do that becomes public.

During the process, meaning when there are not yet enough votes to cause closure, who can see which user(s) voted to close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only moderators can see that....